# QVariant void value not ignored as it ought to be

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm having trouble understanding the behavior of QVariant for Q_OBJECT subclasses(GVPalette* inherits from BasicItemNode which has the Q_OBJECT macro). The compiler error is

```
/qobject.h:471:   instantiated from ‘T qobject_cast(QObject*) [with T = GVPalette*]’
/qvariant.h:584:  instantiated from ‘static T QtPrivate::QVariantValueHelper<T>::object(const QVariant&) [with T = GVPalette*]’
/qvariant.h:100:  instantiated from ‘static ReturnType QtPrivate::ObjectInvoker<Derived, Argument, ReturnType>::invok
                  e(Argument)  [with Derived = QtPrivate::QVariantValueHelper<GVPalette*>, 
                  Argument = const QVariant&, ReturnType = GVPalette*]’
/qvariant.h:593:   instantiated from ‘T qvariant_cast(const QVariant&) [with T = GVPalette*]’
/CLSMetaType.cpp:50:   instantiated from here
/BasicItemNode.h:27: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

Line 2 in snippet below corresponds to CLSMetaType.cpp:50 and Line 6. corresponds to BasicItemNode.h:27

```
CLSMetaType.cpp
if(variant.canConvert<GVPalette*>()) {
  1.//retVal = variant.value<GVPalette*>()->objectName();
  2. GVPalette* gv = variant.value<GVPalette*>();
  3. retVal = gv->objectName();
}

BasicItemNode.h
4. class BasicItemNode : public QObject
5. {
6.   Q_OBJECT
```

Qt5- Opensource version
g++ - 4.6.3

Comment: Did you add Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(GVPalette*)?

Comment: Does `GVPalette` use the Q_OBJECT macro?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: Yes. Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(GVPalette*) has been defined
@cmannett85: GVPalette inherits from BasicItemNode
i.e., `GVPalette: public BasicItemNode` and `BasicItemNode: public QOBject` and I believe this implies GVPalette to be using the Q_OBJECT macro

Comment: @rahul It doesn't: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT

Comment: @cmannett85 Thanks for the tip, it helped resolve the error.